# More Granular Closure Compiler Flags?

Tags: javascript, performance, minify, google-closure-compiler

I am using closure compiler to minfiy and concatenate my scripts and I would like to use the `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS` flag to get even more minifying magic out of it. However some of the scripts I have create warnings when I use this flag and do not function. I would like to instead of passing that one flag step through a bunch of smaller options and see which one breaks it and maybe I wont get 100% the size reduction being offered but closer.

Are there any smaller individual flags to pass to google closure compiler options to turn on individual features of the `'ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS'` flag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "no".

The jump between `SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS` and `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS` may seem huge, but it really comes down to two major issues:

1. dead code elimination
2. property renaming

For both of these items, the compiler needs the same set of information in order to do this correctly. It needs:

- Details on every reference to your code - both within the code itself as well as references outside your compiled code.
- Information on what external libraries, symbols or code snippets the compiled code uses.

By knowing these two pieces of information, the compiler can both safely rename public/global properties and variables as well as completely eliminate code that is never used.

Moving to `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS` can be a lot of work, but it can also produce large payoffs in code size and performance. Tips to help the process along:

- Read and understand the [What to watch out for](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#dangers) section of the official documentation.
- Check out the [FAQ](https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/wiki/FAQ#My_code_broke_when_using_advanced_optimizations!_How_do_I_figure) in the compiler project for tips on debugging compiled code
- Use `warning_level=VERBOSE`. While it does produce more warnings, it helps identify things like missing properties which are often the culprit in broken code.
- Ask lots of questions

Answer (score 0):

You can use the java api to tune the compilers optimizations. Basically you customize the command line:
http://blog.bolinfest.com/2009/11/calling-closure-compiler-from-java.html

Alternately, you can create a custom build of the compiler and twiddle with the options used for advanced mode:

see: applyFullCompilationOptions

in: CompilationLevel.java

http://closure-compiler.googlecode.com/git-history/805436ff85a6975fb482aa298c8f3bce4a2a832f/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/CompilationLevel.java